# How does referring to class name through 'this' keyword while calling another constructor from a constructor set values to an object?

Tags: java, oop, constructor, this

When calling a constructor from a constructor, we use the 'this' keyword. The 'this' keyword refers to the class name. Then how are the values set in the object when we are only referring to the class and not the object?

```
Student random = new student();
class Student {
  int roll;

  student() {
    this student(13);
  }

  student(int roll) {
    this.roll = roll;
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be `this(13);`, not `this student (13);`. And mind the case, `student` is not `Student`.

Comment: A remark: a constructor must always be spelled exactly the same as the class name (`student() { ... }` -> `Student() { ... }`).

Comment: It sets values in the object by referring to another constructor. You've answered your own question. But the `this` keyword does *not* 'refer to the class name'.

Answer (score 1):

See, you are making two constructors which has a default value of 13 and one which sets the value. To be more precise, the first constructor `Student()` gets called if no value is given to it and calls the second constructor `Student(int roll)` with a default value of 13.

Then coming to your question, we can refer from one constructor to another using `this`

For eg.

```
public class Car {
 boolean isStart;
 Car() { 
  this(true);
 }
 Car(boolean start) {
  if (start == true) 
   isStart = true;
 }
}
```

In this eg we see that if `Car()` is called with default value this calls the other constructor  with a boolean value.

Comment: In your example, the "this(true)" line, usually "this" refers to the object we called the constructor with. But we don't usually put parameters with object name we place them with class name. For ex  "Student random = new Student (abc)". Here we can't put "random(abc)".  But in the line "this(true)" if "this" is replaced with object then we're doing something like "random(abc)" i.e putting parameters with object.

Comment: @Anurag-210 That will result in a compiler error

Answer (score 0):

`this` keyword doesn't refer to the class name. It refers to the current object. It's not a `static` reference.